# Simple socket server in C# unexpectedly closes connection when trying to write data to client

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to figure out why this C# code:

```
int port = 8080;
var localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

var server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
server.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

Console.WriteLine("Connected!");            // Writes to console when "open" button
                                            // is pushed in browser.

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

while (client.Connected)                    // successfully loops twice.
{
    string message = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);       // Exception is thrown here; data
                                            // is never received in browser.

    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

client.Close();
```

is throwing the following exception (referenced in code comment above):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in
>   your host machine.

The code I'm using on the browser looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <input id=message size=50 />
            <button type="button" onclick="sendMessage();" >Send</button> <br />
            <button type="button" onclick="openSocket();" >Open</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="closeSocket();" >Close</button>
        </div>

        <div id="messages"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var webSocket;
            var messages = document.getElementById("messages");

            function openSocket(){

                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                   writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }

                webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection opened.");
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection closed with event code " + event.code);
                };

                 webSocket.onerror = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };
            }

            function closeSocket(){
                webSocket.close();
            }

            function sendMessage(){
                webSocket.send(message.value);
            }

            function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

...which I know works perfectly, because I can change the line

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

to

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
```

and get a good connection and echo replies from http://websocket.org.

**Note:** Unlike the websocket.org test, the browser never reports that the connection has been opened with the C# server, even though the C# server believes it has established a successful connection.

Comment: The code you posted works fine on my computer. Granted, it's not great code; a hard reset on the connection as you're doing here won't be detected until one tries to write to the socket, so one way or the other you're eventually going to get the exception you see. But on my computer the server successfully sends data to the socket until the "Close" button is pressed. (I never do see the messages on the page, but there's no error on the server side). Maybe you're using a browser that kills the connection when it receives invalid WebSocket traffic?

Comment: I was able to get the [C# app](https://gist.github.com/jdphenix/4bbf06cb24a7e55c5dc0) to get a open connection message to the browser with implementing the WebSockets handshake, but beyond that and the details get a little complicated. I was following this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: Sure enough, when I try your web page in Chrome, I get a different result. The page actually shows the text "undefined\r\nConnection closed with event code 1006". This tells me that the browser is in fact rejecting the data from the server and resetting the connection. Hence the error in the server. In other words, everything is working exactly as designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a TCP socket to communicate with a WebSocket directly. WebSockets are built on top of HTTP, and the initial  request is an HTTP request to do the handshake and upgrade from HTTP connection to WebSocket connection, so you will need to implement a small http server first to handle the HTTP connection  upgrade request.

An upgrade header looks like this

```
    GET /chat HTTP/1.1
    Host: server.example.com
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
    Origin: http://example.com
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

so either you use an existing library or read the relevant parts of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Comment: The try/catch was there before I simplified the code to ask the question.  But you're onto something.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_server#Handshaking